# jQuery - get a certain range of items within an HTML drop-down menu

Tags: jquery, html, drupal, xhtml

I have a range of items in an HTML drop-down menu that I need to find with jQuery so I can then hide them [using `.css('display', 'none')`].

They are (in this example) all the ones between `<option>---- Articles</option>` and `<option>---- Jargon Buster</option`> **except for the first six items in this range**!

Other than these first six, the number and text of all the other options within this range will vary (apart from from the leading `------` ).

I'm thinking maybe I can utilse the selectors `$("#edit-menu-parent option:contains('---- Articles')"` and `$("#edit-menu-parent option:contains('---- Jargon Buster')"` somehow, but I'm not sure how these can be used to get the items in between them.

Any ideas?

```
<select id="edit-menu-parent" class="form-select menu-title-select" name="menu[parent]">
<option>---- Clients</option>
<option>---- Testimonials</option>
<option>-- Resources</option>
<option>---- Articles</option>
<option>------ Accessibilty Articles</option>
<option>------ Usability Articles</option>
<option>------ Charities Articles</option>
<option>------ Public Sector Articles</option>
<option>------ Web Development Articles</option>
<option>------ Social Media Articles</option>
<option>------ Are Your Online Forms</option>
<option>------ Benefits of Web Standards</option>
<option>------ Benefits of web accessibility</option>
<option>------ Increase Donations to Your</option>
<option>------ Need More Web Traffic? Get</option>
<option>------ The Secret to Successful ALT</option>
<option>------ Top 10 Email Marketing Tips</option>
<option>------ What PAS 78 Means for Your</option>
<option>------ What is Web Accessibility?</option>
<option>---- Jargon Buster</option>
<option>---- Web Design Tips</option>
<option>------ Colour blindness</option>
<option>------ Create a custom 404 page</option>
<option>------ Download time and usability</option>
<option>------ Full stop to the end of alt</option>
<option>------ Javascript and navigation</option>
<option>---- Your Industry News</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my test HTML file I tried both calling `.hide()` and `.css("display", "none")`, but none of them seemed to work in Safari(Mac), but worked as expected in Firefox(Mac).
First I thought that the jQuery selector is wrong, but the same happens even if I select simply `#edit-menu-parent option`.

I created a script that finds the index of start and end elements and then `slice()`-s out the required items for deletion. However, I used `remove()` which didn't work otherwise. Since it was said that the first six elements must remain there, I have this `start+6` there.

```
var options =  $("#edit-menu-parent option");
var start = options.index( $("option:contains(---- Articles)" ));
var end = options.index( $("option:contains(---- Jargon Buster)" ));
options.slice(start+6,end).remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

The [**:contains**](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains) approach you describe should work. I couldn't see why not.

`OPTION`s are nothing but ordinary children of a parent element, and all of JQuery's filtering possibilities should apply without restriction.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered grouping your dropdownlist?

```
    <select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

[W3 Schools optgroup](http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)

Then you can hide/show the whole group instead?

Comment: That's a good idea, but unfortunately the list is created dynamically and I would need to delve into Drupal's innards to get it to work. I'm sure it's possible though.

Answer (score 1):

use these functions: http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/